# dynamically increasing width of li based on text value

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` in which there are some `<li>`.I want width of li to increase based on value of text ?

sample code :

```
<ul class="navTopstories">
    <li>Onsafsf sdsfsfs fsdsdfsdf</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>Three</li>      
</ul>
```

css :

```
.navTopstories li,.navWorld li{
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: remove "width: 80px;" ?

Comment: Simple remove the width to make the `<li>` take up as much space as is available??

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the final effect you are looking to create?

Comment: You could do min-width: 80px; instead of width: 80px; also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete:

```
width: 80px;
```

and/or set on ul/li:

```
width: auto;
```

Comment: `width: auto;` will fill the entire container since it's block element.

Answer (score 1):

By default an LI is a block element, meaning it will take up as much width as possible. Specifying the `width` property is restricting the box model to just 80px. To make the box only as wide as the content you need to change the LI to an inline element:

```
.navTopstories li,.navWorld li{
    width: 80px;
```

into

```
.navTopstories li,.navWorld li{
    display: inline;
```

This will make the LI flexible and fit the content, however it will also bump the LI against each other as the browser now thinks they are words in a sentence. To get around this, we add another element to the mix, the `after` pseudo-element:

```
.navTopstories li:after, .navWorld li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height:1em;
}
```

This creates a new block element after the LI element that is taking up as much width as possible (100%) which breaks the LI on either side of it onto two lines. You need `content:" "` to make the pseudo element work, and I've added the `height` to show some white space between the LI so you can see that they are separated.

And here's a JSFiddle :)

http://jsfiddle.net/7LtQN/2/

Happy Coding :)